# How find if a CheckBoxList is true or false in table?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I put in a table asp more characters before I put one checkboxlist, that in code did in design mode.
This is my table:

```
<asp:Table ID="TBL_Selections" runat="server" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="5">
                </asp:Table>
```

In this table i populate with variable. Some variable have CheckBoxList, every CheckBoxList have an ID, i create that with that comand:

```
DDL.ID = "DDL_" & SelectedCategory & "_" & SubAssy & "_" & ProductType
                    RBL.ID = "RBL_" & SelectedCategory & "_" & SubAssy & "_" & ProductType
                    CBL.ID = "CBL_" & SelectedCategory & "_" & SubAssy & "_" & ProductType
```

Now i try to find value of CheckBoxList(true or false), with another button, my code is like that but doesn't work:

```
    For Each gvr As GridViewRow In TBL_Selections.Rows
        Dim myCBL As CheckBoxList = gvr.FindControl("chkListMyCheckBoxList")
        if myCBl.Text = true then
           ' do something
        End if
    Next
```

My code salt in first for.

Thanks for help

Comment: You use a table instead of a GridView. That's why you can't loop the table's rows like they were `GridViewRow`. My advice is to use a GridView and put your `CheckBoxList` in a `TemplateField`. Then you also don't need to fiddle around with the `ID`, it will get a unique one automatically. More important, you don't need to care about re-creating everything on every postback. Because that you have to do with your dynamical table rows. A `GridView` is rendered as table on clientside.

Comment: I change with Table and TableRow but the same problem

Comment: You haven't even mentioned your problem. What means "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Just jump this for and that is it